# CodeIgniter version 3.1.5 requires the class filenames to be in ucfirst like manner but I have multiple sites which have filenames in lowercase

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

CodeIgniter version 3.1.5 requires the class filenames to be in ucfirst like manner but I have multiple sites which have filenames in lowercase. Is it a good practice to update the core files of CI 3.1.5 and accepts the files names as is without converting it into ucfirst like manner

Comment: It's definetly not a good ideia to change the CI core, otherwise you'll have to change it every time you update code igniter version

Comment: Is there any specific reason why CI community has made it essential to specify the class file names in ucfirst like manner only? This was not the convention in the earlier versions. In terms of security, does it have any impact?

Comment: Also I would not update the core files directly. I would override the method in child class and update the method definition in child class

Comment: I'd already transfer the whole project which made in CI2.3 and it converts to CI3.1.6. You simply download core folder of CI3.1.6 from [https://codeigniter.com/download] here and put your MVC structure into it and capitalize all controllers and models files. That's it. It gonna take hardly 1 Hours

Comment: @JaiminVyas : I have already done that, but I have multiple sites and capitalizing all controllers and models is equivalent to creating new files, which would result in loosing the entire history associated with the older file name. That is only concern

Comment: @PriyankaThorve : I think you must have to go with your comfort level. :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [Link](https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/commit/20292311636837e120d205e470e41826820feb46) , Here Given How codignitier Core Libraries add More consistency in capitalization.